# NotifyPropChanged error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to C#. I am trying to run these 2 pieces of code but got stuck at 2 error. I listed down the code and the errors, what should I do to get rid of the errors?

```
private void NotifyPropChanged(string propName)
{
  PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
}
```

> cannot convert from 'System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs' to 'System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs'

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
   Document d = new Document("Test Document");

   d.PropertyChanged += delegate (object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
     Console.WriteLine("Document property changed:{0}", e.PropertyName);
   };
```

> Cannot convert anonymous method to delegate type 'System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventHandler' because the parameter types do not match the delegate parameter types

Comment: What does this have to do with asp.net?

Comment: Can you post the code where you defined the `PropertyChanged` event?

Answer (score 1):

Change your `PropertyChanged` definition to:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Also, you might be attempting to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but if you were, I would expect there to be a 3rd error: "does not implement interface". Make sure that you are inheriting from INotifyPropertyChanged if that is what you intend to do.